# fisher.exact test not returning expected p-value

Tags: r, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I am trying to run Fisher Exact Test, however, I get unexpected results.
I thought the `two.sided` p-value should be twice as large than the minimal one-sided p-value. However, the results do not hold. How is the `two.sided` p-value obtained in this test?

Here is the example:

```
tab <- rbind(c(176, 15),
             c(430, 53))

> fisher.test(tab, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value
[1] 0.2577816
> fisher.test(tab, alternative = "greater")$p.value 
[1] 0.9146759
> fisher.test(tab, alternative = "less")$p.value  
[1] 0.1416532
```

I tried computing the probabilities using `hyper` functions, but I obtain the same results as the one-sided tests.

Comment: The distribution of the counts in Fisher's Exact Test has a hypergeometric distribution, which is, in general, asymmetric. Hence the results you have obtained. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16319/one-sided-fishers-exact-test-and-its-complement) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304107/two-sided-vs-one-sided-p-value-is-there-a-special-case-with-fishers-exact-test)